# Is it legal to create an ebook from the book I bought and sell it?

Tags: pdf, amazon, ebook-management, copyright

This book is copyrighted 2011, can I make it to an ebook and sell it online?

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it's about legal advice more than about ebooks. We don't give legal advice here (and what I'm about to say is not legal advice). That said, to really simplify things: a copyright generally means that the person who owns the copyright is the only person who has the right to make copies, including electronic ones. Details depend on the country of the copyright, but no, you generally do not have rights to make copies of a book and sell it if you don't own the copyright. That's not legal advice, but you need to hire a lawyer before thinking about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

No.  And since an answer requires 30 characters, no again.